# Split text file and rename on the basis of first column

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I am trying to split a very long text file which looks like this:

```
AA1 0.1 0.2 0.3
AA2 0.5 0.6 0.7
AA3 0.5 0.1 0.3
```

I want to have save each line in one individual text file. I know that split command would do it and also the following awk command: awk '{filename = FILENAME NR; print > filename; close(filename)}'

BUT I would like each next file to be named after the first column like this:

```
AA1.txt
AA2.txt
AA3.txt
```

Is there any easy way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using awk

```
awk '{cmd="echo " $0 ">" $1; system(cmd)}' file
```

if you dont want 1st column

```
awk '{cmd="echo " $2" "$3" "$4 ">" $1  ;system(cmd)}' file
```

Comment: Why do you start an external process for the echo? You can just use `{print $0 > filename}` - as other answers have shown before. You gave an example of how it should **not** be done!

Comment: There are no of ways to do it

Comment: Yes, but why did you suggest the worst of them? Also this is vulnerable against shell code injection (for zero worth). Dynamic code creation is always something what should be handled with care and I see no reason why it should be used here.

Answer (score 4):

You can  use a very simple awk script as

`awk '{print $0 > $1".txt"}' inputFile`

will creates files

```
AA1                        
AA2                        
AA3
```

Test

```
$ ls AA*
AA1  AA2  AA3

$ cat AA1
AA1 0.1 0.2 0.3
$ cat AA2
AA2 0.5 0.6 0.7
$ cat AA3
AA3 0.5 0.1 0.3
```

Comment: it should be $1."txt", i wont work if you dont use quotes

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
awk '{print >> $1".txt"; close($1".txt")}' input.txt
```

It uses the first column's value (`$1`) plus the extension ".txt" as the name of the output file for the current line.

As you already shown in the question, it is a good idea to close the file afterwards because too many different values in the first column in a big input file could lead to too many open file descriptors.

---

If you want to omit the first column in output - as it will not change - you can use this:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ", $i >> $1".txt"};printf "\n" >> $1".txt"; close($1".txt")}' input.txt
```

It iterates over every column starting at the second and finally adds a new line.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following either by pipeing the input text into awk or by using the input file as a parameter with awk

```
cat test.txt | awk '{ print $0 > $1.txt }'
```

or

```
awk '{ print $0 > $1.txt }' test.txt
```

Comment: This is faster than the accepted answer by Hackaholic.